# How can I change the created classes to the jar file in Android?

Tags: android

When I open the Android Studio, I check only the `mark this project as a library` option to create the my classes and also I uncheck the `create activity` and `create custom launcher icon` option.

After creating the project, I wrote two classes and I could compile that successfully. Now I have `Example1.java` and `Example2.java` in `src` folder in my project. I want to have the `java` classes as the `jar` file  to use in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you have library modules. You just put your classes into that library with your asserts like images etc. Then you can link to your library in your main module `build.gradle` like this:

```
dependencies {
    // dependencies of the main project
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    // [...]
    compile project(':your-library-module-name')
}
```

I hope that path help you on orientation:

`/app/build.gradle` <- there you put the dependency block from above
`/your-library-module-name/src/main/java/your/package/Example1.java`
`/your-library-module-name/src/main/java/your/package/Example2.java`